# Sencha 2.2 App in PhoneGap Project to PhoneGap Build, BB10

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-build

I have created from the command line a PhoneGap Project (2.9.0).
In the WWW folder I have put the folder that was in my Build folder of my Sencha Touch App.
That folder is actually name after the app's name and contains Package and Native Folders.

I added the phonegap line inmy index.html and zipped the WWW folder which I uploaded on the PhoneGap Build.

It seems to build fine for Windows Phone, Android and HP.
It does not for Apple (I dont have keys yet, so it's normal).
But it crashes for BB10. It tells me there is too many files in my WWW Folder.
So I clicked the error report and read about that particular case. It says that if you have about 200-250 it won't work. In my case I only have 107 files... So Why does it not work and how Can I make it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214153/how-to-run-a-project-having-sencha-bb10-phonegap-cordova-webworks)

Still if you have problem, then you can check the image sizes you have used. if you can reduce the size of images, I think it will work.

But the error it is reporting "too many files" also signify that the required files are missing. do check that too.