# How to run a Project having Sencha BB10 Phonegap/Cordova Webworks?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, blackberry-10, cordova-3, sencha-cmd

I have already coded sencha app, I want to build it for Blackberry 10 now I don;'t understand appropriate cordova version to work with and getting error running blackberry 10 with cordova 3.0. Documentation given at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_blackberry10_index.md.html doesn't seem sufficient. any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to run a Project having Sencha BB10 Phonegap/Cordova Webworks ?

Frameworks

Sencha           :   Provides HTML5-based app development tools and services for building universal apps that run on any device.

PhoneGap/Cordova :   We are using 2.7 and below. As with cordova-cli we were not able to create build for BB10 because of some version incompatibility issues.

WebWorks         :   Don't get confuse with this one as this is needed to run some commands to port app to BB10 phone. 
                     The BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK offers support for developing applications for the BlackBerry 10 OS in 
                     javascript + html platform.

Device           :  BB10

Steps

Step 1: Running PhoneGap on BB10

> Download Phone Gap Version (we downloaded 2.7)

```
    > Follow the steps mentioned in this link
             [Click Here][1]
              https://github.com/ctetreault/incubator-cordova-docs/blob/master/docs/en/edge/guide/getting-started/blackberry/index.md

    > Create New Project from above step and run on device. 

    > Good to go for next step. Now Your project has all the features from Phonegap working in BB10 (like Camera, geolocation....). Generally controlled by plugin.xml and config.xml. Though there are few BB10 specific features or enteries like  <rim:permissions> which is required by BB device to access core features
```

Step 2
    As Sencha Doesn't supports BB10 directly. So please perform these steps to run Sencha thing on BB10(Phonegap Project)

```
    > Go inside the build folder in Sencha project published by Sencha Touch App/Architect.

> Copy all the contents (resources, splash, touch, all js) from the package/<App  Name> folder (this folder depends upon Sencha cmd build) to 
  the BB10 phonegap www folder. 

    > Remember not to overide config.xml as BB10 has it's separate config.xml having some of it's specific features.

    > Now open index.html and change the import of phonegap.js to the specific version you are using. Check inside BB10 phonegap project you will find specific cordova2.XXX.js
```

Follow these steps and hopefully you will end up smiling.

Comment: thanks user2790034 this worked like charm.. also the mentioned link is
[here](https://github.com/ctetreault/incubator-cordova-docs/blob/master/docs/en/edge/guide/getting-started/blackberry/index.md)

Comment: I was able to run this on 3.1 [see it now](http://techbirds.in/?p=500). For Sencha build. Make appropriate build using sencha cmd  `sencha build app package`. Now place the `<sencha app dir>/build/package/<appName>` to www folder of your Cordova project.  Build your cordova project. I think it will work provided you used `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in your index.html file and the appropriate API of cordova for calling camera and other device features.